# Change dataframe to index value pair

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I have a pandas dataframe 'df' of shape 2000x50 which appears as:

```
       Col1     Col2   Col3
row1  0.046878  0.298156  0.743520  
row2  0.442526  0.881977  0.885514  
row3  0.075382  0.622636  0.706607
```

Rows and cols don't have a consistent naming in my real scenario.

I want to create a data frame with multi index as:

```
(row1, col1), 0.046878
(row3, col2), 0.622636, etc
```

Is there a more concise way to do this other than to extract column names and indexes, form cartisian product to create indexes like (row1, col1) etc and flatten the values stored in 'df'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) for `Series` and then [`to_frame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.to_frame.html) for `DataFrame`:

```
df = df.stack().to_frame('col')
print (df)
                col
row1 Col1  0.046878
     Col2  0.298156
     Col3  0.743520
row2 Col1  0.442526
     Col2  0.881977
     Col3  0.885514
row3 Col1  0.075382
     Col2  0.622636
     Col3  0.706607
```

And then [`sample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html):

```
df = df.stack().to_frame('col').sample(n=3)
print (df)
                col
row1 Col2  0.298156
row3 Col1  0.075382
     Col2  0.622636
```

Comment: How do I extract from this (row1, col3), (row3, col1), etc randomly ?

Comment: @Zanam You should familiarize yourself with MultiIndexes :)